# Official Spring security oauth2 example doesn't work because of cookies clashing(authorization code mechanism)

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

According the tutorial [Spring Boot and OAuth2](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_authserver)

I have following project structure:

[image]

And following source code:

**SocialApplication.class:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableOAuth2Client
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Order(200)
public class SocialApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

    @RequestMapping({ "/user", "/me" })
    public Map<String, String> user(Principal principal) {
        Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        map.put("name", principal.getName());
        return map;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**").permitAll().anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/")).and().logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll().and().csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and()
                .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http.antMatcher("/me").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
            // @formatter:on
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SocialApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<OAuth2ClientContextFilter> oauth2ClientFilterRegistration(OAuth2ClientContextFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean<OAuth2ClientContextFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<OAuth2ClientContextFilter>();
        registration.setFilter(filter);
        registration.setOrder(-100);
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("github")
    public ClientResources github() {
        return new ClientResources();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("facebook")
    public ClientResources facebook() {
        return new ClientResources();
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter() {
        CompositeFilter filter = new CompositeFilter();
        List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
        filters.add(ssoFilter(facebook(), "/login/facebook"));
        filters.add(ssoFilter(github(), "/login/github"));
        filter.setFilters(filters);
        return filter;
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter(ClientResources client, String path) {
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
                path);
        OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(client.getClient(), oauth2ClientContext);
        filter.setRestTemplate(template);
        UserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(
                client.getResource().getUserInfoUri(),
                client.getClient().getClientId());
        tokenServices.setRestTemplate(template);
        filter.setTokenServices(new UserInfoTokenServices(
                client.getResource().getUserInfoUri(),
                client.getClient().getClientId()));
        return filter;
    }

}

class ClientResources {

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails client = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private ResourceServerProperties resource = new ResourceServerProperties();

    public AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public ResourceServerProperties getResource() {
        return resource;
    }
}
```

**index.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <base href="/"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login</h1>
<div class="container unauthenticated">
    With Facebook: <a href="/login/facebook">click here</a>
</div>
<div class="container authenticated" style="display: none">
    Logged in as: <span id="user"></span>
    <div>
        <button onClick="logout()" class="btn btn-primary">Logout</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="/webjars/js-cookie/js.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
            if (settings.type == 'POST' || settings.type == 'PUT'
                || settings.type == 'DELETE') {
                if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/
                        .test(settings.url))) {
                    // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-XSRF-TOKEN",
                        Cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN'));
                }
            }
        }
    });
    $.get("/user", function (data) {
        $("#user").html(data.userAuthentication.details.name);
        $(".unauthenticated").hide();
        $(".authenticated").show();
    });
    var logout = function () {
        $.post("/logout", function () {
            $("#user").html('');
            $(".unauthenticated").show();
            $(".authenticated").hide();
        });
        return true;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**application.yml:**

```
server:
  port: 8080
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      client-id: acme
      client-secret: acmesecret
      scope: read,write
      auto-approve-scopes: '.*'

facebook:
  client:
    clientId: 233668646673605
    clientSecret: 33b17e044ee6a4fa383f46ec6e28ea1d
    accessTokenUri: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
    userAuthorizationUri: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
    tokenName: oauth_token
    authenticationScheme: query
    clientAuthenticationScheme: form
  resource:
    userInfoUri: https://graph.facebook.com/me
github:
  client:
    clientId: bd1c0a783ccdd1c9b9e4
    clientSecret: 1a9030fbca47a5b2c28e92f19050bb77824b5ad1
    accessTokenUri: https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token
    userAuthorizationUri: https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize
    clientAuthenticationScheme: form
  resource:
    userInfoUri: https://api.github.com/user

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
```

But when I open browser and try to hit `http://localhost:8080`

In browser console I see:

```
(index):44 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'details' of undefined
    at Object.success ((index):44)
    at j (jquery.js:3073)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3185)
    at x (jquery.js:8251)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js:8598)
```

in code:

```
$.get("/user", function (data) {
        $("#user").html(data.userAuthentication.details.name);
        $(".unauthenticated").hide();
        $(".authenticated").show();
    });
```

It happens because `/user` response with 302 status code and js callback try to parse result of `localhost:8080`:

[image]

I don't understand why this redirect happens. Can you explain this behavior and help to fix it?

### UPDATE

I took this code from https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2

### important:

It reproduces **only after I start client application.**

### P.S.

**How to reproduce:**

> To test the new features you can just run both apps and visit
>   localhost:9999/client in your browser. The client app will redirect to
>   the local Authorization Server, which then gives the user the usual
>   choice of authentication with Facebook or Github. Once that is
>   complete control returns to the test client, the local access token is
>   granted and authentication is complete (you should see a "Hello"
>   message in your browser). If you are already authenticated with Github
>   or Facebook you may not even notice the remote authentication

### ANSWER:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50349078/2674303

Comment: Can you create a minimal repo to reproduce? Would be easier to provide a fix

Comment: @Tarun Lalwani, you can find it here:https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2/tree/master/auth-server

Comment: are you available for a quick chat. pls join https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170569/room-for-vsoni-and-gstackoverflow

Comment: what should be set as a callback url for Github?

Comment: resolution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50349078/2674303

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I've found the problem. I see this behaviour due the fact of cookies clashing for client and server if you start both applications on localhost.

It happens due the fact of usage wrong property for context.

So to fix application you need to replace:

```
server:
  context-path: /client
```

with

```
server:  
  servlet:
    context-path: /client
```

### P.S.

I've created issue on github:

https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2/issues/80

and made the pull request:

https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2/pull/81

### P.S.2

Finally my pull request was merged:
https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2/pull/81

Answer (score 16):

**Update: 15-May-2018**

As you have already found out the solution, the issue happens because of the `JSESSIONID` gets overwritten

[image: Session ID replaced]

**Update: 10-May-2018**

Well your persistence with the 3rd bounty has finally paid off. I started digging into what was different between the two examples you had in the repo

If you look at the `manual` repo and `/user` mapping

```
@RequestMapping("/user")
public Principal user(Principal principal) {
    return principal;
}
```

As you can see you are returning the `principal` here, you get more details from the same object. Now in your code that you run from `auth-server` folder

```
@RequestMapping({ "/user", "/me" })
public Map<String, String> user(Principal principal) {
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("name", principal.getName());
    return map;
}
```

As you can see you only returned the `name` in the `/user` mapping and your UI logic runs below

```
$.get("/user", function(data) {
    $("#user").html(data.userAuthentication.details.name);
    $(".unauthenticated").hide();
    $(".authenticated").show();
});
```

So the json response returned from `/user` api expected to have `userAuthentication.details.name` by the UI doesn't have that details. Now if I updated the method like below in the same project

```
@RequestMapping({"/user", "/me"})
public Map<String, Object> user(Principal principal) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("name", principal.getName());
    OAuth2Authentication user = (OAuth2Authentication) principal;
    map.put("userAuthentication", new HashMap<String, Object>(){{
       put("details", user.getUserAuthentication().getDetails());
    }});
    return map;
}
```

And then check the application, it works

[image: OAuth Success]

**Original Answer**

So the issue that you are running wrong project from the repo. The project you are running is `auth-server` which is for launching your own `oauth` server. The project that you need to run is inside `manual` folder.

Now if you look at the below code

```
OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter facebookFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
        "/login/facebook");
OAuth2RestTemplate facebookTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(facebook(), oauth2ClientContext);
facebookFilter.setRestTemplate(facebookTemplate);
UserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(facebookResource().getUserInfoUri(),
        facebook().getClientId());
tokenServices.setRestTemplate(facebookTemplate);
facebookFilter.setTokenServices(
        new UserInfoTokenServices(facebookResource().getUserInfoUri(), facebook().getClientId()));
return facebookFilter;
```

And the actual code you run has

```
private Filter ssoFilter(ClientResources client, String path) {
    OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
            path);
    OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(client.getClient(), oauth2ClientContext);
    filter.setRestTemplate(template);
    UserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(
            client.getResource().getUserInfoUri(), client.getClient().getClientId());
    tokenServices.setRestTemplate(template);
    filter.setTokenServices(tokenServices);
    return filter;
}
```

In your current the `userdetails` from the `facebook` doesn't get collected. That's is why you see an error

[image: Error]

Because when you logged in the user, you didn't collect its user details. So when you access the details, its not there. And hence you get an error

If you run the correct `manual` folder, it works

[image: Working]

Comment: It still doesn't work. Looks like you didn't understand the problem. You need to start Client and server - it is 2 different applications!!! Please reread my question from scratch

Comment: Please mention which folder you are using for the client application?

Comment: you can find it in **src/test/java**

Comment: any news from your side?

Comment: @gstackoverflow, I am not still on same page with you. The code in the `auth-server` folder runs fine after my changes, it listens on `8080`, why would you run both `src/test/java` and `src/main/java` as well?

Comment: because it is mentioned in tutorial. https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_authserver

Comment: **Testing the OAuth2 Client**
**To test the new features you can just run both apps and visit http://localhost:9999/client in your browser. The client app will redirect to the local Authorization Server, which then gives the user the usual choice of authentication with Facebook or Github. Once that is complete control returns to the test client, the local access token is granted and authentication is complete (you should see a "Hello" message in your browser). If you are already authenticated with Github or Facebook you may not even notice the remote authentication.**

Comment: This you should have added in the question as well to make it clear. I was not debugging it this way from the start, anyways will have a look now

Comment: I've added it to the topic

Comment: @gstackoverflow, great. I was just debugging your issue only. I had reproduced the `302` but was just debugging the java call to see what's wrong

Answer (score 6):

I see two queries in your post.

**ONE-**

```
(index):44 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'details' of undefined
```

This was happening because you were perhaps running a wrong project (i.e. auth-server) which has a bug. The repo contains other similar projects also without bug. If you run the project **manual** or **github** this error will not appear. In these projects the javascript code is correctly handling the data which is returned by the server after authentication.

**TWO-**

`/user` **response with 302 status code:**

To understanding why this is happening lets see the security configuration of this application.

The end points `"/"`, `"/login**"` and `"/logout"` are accessible to all.
All the other end points including `"/user"` requires authentication because you have used

```
.anyRequest().authenticated().and().exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/"))
```

So any request that is not authenticated will be redirected to the authentication entry point i.e. `"/"`, asking user for authentication. It does not depend on whether your client application is started or not. As long as the request is not authenticated it will be redirected to `"/"`. This why the spring controller is responding with status 302. Once you have authenticated with either of **facebook** or **github**, subsequent requests to `"/user"` end point will respond success with 200.

**AND NEXT-**

The endpoint `"/me"` in your application is secured as a secured resource with `@EnableResourceServer`. Since `ResourceServerConfiguration` has higher precedence (ordered 3 by default) than `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`(default 100, anyway it has already ordered explicitly lower than 3 with @Order annotation in the code) so ResourceServerConfiguration will apply for this endpoint. That means if the request is not authenticated then it **will not** be redirected to authentication entry point, it will rather return a response **401**. Once you are authenticated it will response success with 200.

Hope this will clarify all your questions.

**UPDATE-** to answer your question

The repository link that you have provided in your post contains many projects. The projects **auth-server**, **manual** and **github** are all similar (provide the same functionality i.e. authentication with facebook and github). Just the `index.html` in **auth-server** projet has one bug. If you correct this bug that is replace

```
$("#user").html(data.userAuthentication.details.name);
```

with

```
$("#user").html(data.name);
```

it will also run fine. All the three projects will give the same output.

Comment: What do you mean "wrong"? I want to demo this one. How can I achieve it?

Comment: it really doesn't help

Comment: I run right project. My question related with the **auth-server** project

Comment: @gstackoverflow- are you available for a quick chat? join the chat room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170569/room-for-vsoni-and-gstackoverflow if you are available.