# How to sign up new user via Spring Social Facebook?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I am having a website (Angular App) which I can reach on https://localhost:4200 and a server (pure REST API) that is on https://localhost:8443.

Since the REST endpoints are secured, a user must login on my server. Obviously I want users to be able to signup using Facebook and further communicate with my server after login.

---

According to [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/2.0.0.M4/reference/htmlsingle/#enabling-provider-sign-in-with-code-providersignincontroller-code)

> `POST /signin/{providerId}` - Initiates the sign in flow.

that is why there is a button that does just this:

```
<form ngNoForm name="fb_signin" id="fb_signin" action="https://localhost:8443/signin/facebook" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="email">
  <button type="submit">SIGNING</button>
</form>
```

From there, everything works fine for some time. The user gets redirected to Facebook's authorization page where the authorization button gets clicked. After that the user gets redirected to https://localhost:8443/signin/facebook.

---

It seems that per default, in case the user is unknown, there will be a another redirect to https://localhost:8443/signup ([see docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/2.0.0.M4/reference/htmlsingle/#enabling-provider-sign-in-with-code-providersignincontroller-code))

> If the provider user ID matches more than one existing connection, `ProviderSignInController` will redirect to the application’s sign in URL to offer the user a chance to sign in through another provider or with their username and password. The request to the sign in URL will have an "`error`" query parameter set to "`multiple_users`" to indicate the problem so that the page can communicate it to the user. The default sign in URL is "`/signin`" (relative to the application root), but can be customized by setting the `signInUrl` property.

On my serer this looks like this ([borrowed from a sample application](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples)):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public SignUpForm signupForm(WebRequest request) {
    Connection<?> connection = providerSignInUtils.getConnectionFromSession(request);
    if (connection != null) {
        request.setAttribute("message", new Message(MessageType.INFO, "Your " + StringUtils.capitalize(connection.getKey().getProviderId()) + " account is not associated with a Spring Social Showcase account. If you're new, please sign up."), WebRequest.SCOPE_REQUEST);
        return SignUpForm.fromProviderUser(connection.fetchUserProfile());
    } else {
        return new SignUpForm();
    }
}
```

And here are my issues:

First of all I need to know what I am supposed to do at this endpoint. The user authorized my app, but my server does not know the user yet so do I

- `connection.fetchUserProfile()` and save the new user to my database
- something else?

Second, I do not know how I am supposed to redirect back to my website from here which, as explained, lies on https://localhost:4200. But of course, my server does not know that.

Is there a chance somebody can guide me through this?

---

This is the `SocialConfig`

```
@Configuration
@EnableSocial
public class SocialConfig implements SocialConfigurer {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(SocialConfig.class);

    @Value("${spring.social.facebook.appId}")
    String facebookAppId;

    @Value("${spring.social.facebook.appSecret}")
    String facebookSecret;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    @Scope(value="singleton", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator() {
        ConnectionFactoryRegistry registry = new ConnectionFactoryRegistry();

        registry.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookConnectionFactory(
                facebookAppId,
                facebookSecret
        ));

        return registry;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value="singleton", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository() {
        return new JdbcUsersConnectionRepository(dataSource, connectionFactoryLocator(), Encryptors.noOpText());
    }

    @Override
    public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer cfConfig, Environment env) {
        LOGGER.debug("Adding connection factories");
        cfConfig.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookConnectionFactory(
                env.getProperty("facebook.clientId"),
                env.getProperty("facebook.clientSecret")));

    }

    @Override
    public UserIdSource getUserIdSource() {
        return new AuthenticationNameUserIdSource();
    }

    @Override
    public UsersConnectionRepository getUsersConnectionRepository(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator) {
        return new JdbcUsersConnectionRepository(dataSource, connectionFactoryLocator, Encryptors.noOpText());
    }

    @Bean
    public ProviderSignInController providerSignInController(
            ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator,
            UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository) {
        ProviderSignInController controller = new ProviderSignInController(
                connectionFactoryLocator,
                usersConnectionRepository,
                new SimpleSignInAdapter(new HttpSessionRequestCache()));

        return controller;
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestCache requestCache() {
        return new HttpSessionRequestCache();
    }

    @Bean
    public SignInAdapter signInAdapter() {
        return new SimpleSignInAdapter(new HttpSessionRequestCache());
    }

}
```

Maven dependencies related to Spring Social:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0.M1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-security</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.M4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.M2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-config</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.M2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: See if the tutorial in this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49942640/spring-controller-responds-with-302-status-codespring-security-oauth2spring-b/50007181#50007181 helps?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Hm no, this is a different setup and I think the problem is also different from what I am having. I know why the redirects are coming - what I do not know is how I redirect back to a web client that gets hosted elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

> After that the user gets redirected to https://localhost:8443/signin/facebook.

I think there is another best way of doing so .As your angular webapp
(https://localhost:4200) comprises of webLayer  so directly redirecting via form action is not a better way.You can use **Proxy Routing** [click here](https://blog.talentica.com/2018/02/21/proxy-routing-in-angular-4-applications/)

Now in case of you are using you are using proxy routing u need to configure your proxy port (8443) by command.

> ng serve –proxy-config proxy.conf.json
>     where proxy.conf.json contain your  configuration  https://localhost:8443/

then you need to first authenticate your each user/new user to your server(service layer) & then pass every request through user service layer controller .This will lead to pass every request through your server  and it solve your problem.

> The user authorized my app, but my server does not know the user yet so do I

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. https://localhost:8443/signin/facebook is my OAuth redirect from Facebook to my server. I'm not sure how proxy routing could help here. All the requests are already going through my server anyway.

Comment: The user authorized my app .how does your authorization working?if you are hitting your oauth request  
 https://localhost:8443/signin/facebook  ..after authorization it get back to server .where is the role of your angular webapp?Is it not required  to make a authorize connection between web and service layer ?   I only want to know what is the middleware layer of your angular webapp and services.

Comment: Have you used Spring Social yourself in one of your projects?

Comment: The thing is this: I don't see what this proxy-config does for me except externalizing the URL of my REST API - maybe I'm getting something wrong here? However, as stated in my question I submit a `POST` to `https://localhost:8443/signin/facebook` which triggers the Spring Social magic.  The user gets redirected to the Facebook page and authorizes my app. Then I am receiving the callback from Facebook and somehow end up on `https://localhost:8443/signup` in my browser. I'm either doing something completely wrong or I have to adapt something due to the fact that the web client and the ..

Comment: .. REST API live on two different domains. This "proxy routing" sounds more like a fancy name for externalizing/centralizing other web endpoint URLs?

Answer (score 0):

This is my `signup` PoC code , FYI

```
@Controller
class HomeController : AbstractController() {

  private var sessionStrategy: SessionStrategy = HttpSessionSessionStrategy()

  @Inject
  private lateinit var connectionFactoryLocator: ConnectionFactoryLocator

  @Inject
  private lateinit var usersConnectionRepository: FoodUsersConnectionRepository

  @RequestMapping("/")
  fun index(): String {
    logger.info("index")
    return "index"
  }

  @RequestMapping("/signup")
  fun signup(nativeWebRequest: NativeWebRequest) : String {
    sessionStrategy.getAttribute(nativeWebRequest , ProviderSignInAttempt.SESSION_ATTRIBUTE)
      .takeIf { it != null }
      .also { it ->
        val attempt = it as ProviderSignInAttempt
        val connection = attempt.getConnection(connectionFactoryLocator)
        logger.info("conn.key = {}" , connection.key)
        val user = userDao.save(User(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(8) , RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(8)))
        val connRepo: ConnectionRepository = usersConnectionRepository.createConnectionRepository(user.id.toString())
        connRepo.addConnection(connection)
      }
    return "signup"
  }

}
```

Points to notes :

I retrieve the connection object set in `ProviderSignInController.handleSignIn()` , it contains freshy (not mapped in db) providerId/providerUserId pair.
And I create a new local user , give it random username/password pair , and link the new providerId/providerUserId to the local user.

This is a simple PoC code , it should be modified to conform to your business logic.

Maybe you can display a form for user to fill-in his nickname or address or something. That's depend on your business logic.